# accessing Provider(google, facebook, email, phone, etc) specific info from FirebaseUser/FirebaseAuth

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

In my app the user can sign in/out with multiple accounts like `Anonymous`, `Google`, `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `phone`, `email`.

Moreover, when more than 1 providers are logged in, I use `FirebaseAuth` `linkWithCredential` and link the new provider credentials with the existing `FirebaseUser`.

I am listening to `FirebaseAuth` `onAuthStateChanged()` to get sign in/out events and it is working as expected.

However, in the listen method, I would like to differentiate between these providers and be able to disable/enable the different providers sign in/out buttons.

How can I know `FirebaseAuth` is currently logged in with which providers?

```
firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map((FirebaseUser user) {
   //do something with the user to understand which of the MULTIPLE providers he/she is currently signed in/out with
});
```

Comment: Do you already try `providerData` from FirebaseUser ?

Comment: @RubensMelo I saw providerData but I don't know how to take advantage of it in order to let's say make switch case to check for all the providers. Can you fill in the comment part of the code snippet with at least a pseudo-code in an answer?